# Cannot display images stored in array automatically in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, image

I am trying to create webpage where the user clicks a button and then the page displays images saved in an array.When I run the code, It displays the source of the images, but not the images. Any tips on what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Slideshow</h1>

<p>Holiday Slideshow</p>


<button type="button" onclick="beginShow()">View Slideshow</button>

<p id="p1"><img id="pic1" src="./assets/pic1.jpg">
Click on "View Slideshow". Click to display slideshow</p>
<script>
var list = [
    "/assets/pic1.jpg",
    "/assets/pic2.jpg",
    "./assets/pic3.jpg",
    "./assets/pic4.jpg"
];

var index = 0;

function beginShow() {
    setTimeout(myTimeout1, 2000) 
    setTimeout(myTimeout2, 4000) 
    setTimeout(myTimeout3, 6000)
    setTimeout(myTimeout4, 8000) 
}
function myTimeout1() {
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = list[0];
}
function myTimeout2() {
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = list[1];
}
function myTimeout3() {
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = list[2];
}
function myTimeout4() {
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = list[3];
}
</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should change the `src` of `pic1`

Comment: `document.getElementById("pic1").src=list[x]`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, when I change the code to what you've suggested, (replacing x with 0,1,2,3) the images do not load when viewing in browser.

Comment: can you make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? so we can test it quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to do it this way you have to change what you assign to innerHTML:

```
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = '<img src=' + list[0] + '>;
```

But I recommend you rather change src attribute of image to list[0]:

```
document.getElementById('pic1').setAttribute('src', list[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I change it to the .setAttribute option, pictures 2,3 and 4 do not load when viewing the code through a web browser. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't just copy pasted it? You need to change parameter too (so change list[0] to list[1], list[2] etc.)

Comment: I changed the parameter for all four lines (so it runs 0 to 3)

Comment: Do you get any error in network tab of dev tools? Because this way you are changing src attribute so it should be downloaded (or at least tried) by the browser...

Comment: I needed full stops before the source in the array. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set those urls to the image instead of its container.

Your code should be written like this.

```
var list = [
    "/assets/pic1.jpg",
    "/assets/pic2.jpg",
    "./assets/pic3.jpg",
    "./assets/pic4.jpg"
];
function showImage(i){
    i = i || 0;
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("pic1").src = list[i];
        i < list.length - 1 && showImage(++i);
    },2000);
}
showImage();
```

Comment: You passed in `src` as the function variable but then used `i` without initializing it.

Comment: @AlexanderDixon Thanks for the hint.

Comment: The iteration is not working properly. In the console, `i` is returning `NaN`. Essentially, the `#pic1` `src` attribute is always returning the initial value, or the first picture.  It does not increment.

Comment: @AlexanderDixon I've fixed it.

Comment: It returned undefined a few times.  This is a learning experience for me, not so much a critique on your code.  Could you please tell if the only way an undefined variable will work is in a `for` loop method?

Comment: You are nearly there.  The only thing is to dynamically set a cap on the iteration.  I assume that is what the `|| 0` should be doing but it does not reset it and since the `++i` keeps going the array item does not exist and returns undefined.

Comment: @AlexanderDixon Sorry for the annoying fixes. I've tested the code and it'll surely work this time.